# CakePHP - loginRedirect - How to redirect to the current page after login?

Tags: authentication, cakephp-2.0, http-redirect

I have a login form that appears on all pages (Layout/default.ctp) and I want to keep the user on the page he logs in on. For example, if he is viewing another user's profile, I want to keep him there after logging in, not redirect him to the $this->Auth->loginRedirect action. Also, another thing about my app is that I have no "authenticated access only" pages, every page is accessible to everyone, but if you're logged in you get additional features.

How can I do that?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this question, writing this code:

UsersController:

```
if($this->Auth->Login()){
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
}
```

In AppController:

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    if($this->here != '/cmap/users/login'){
        $this->Session->write('Auth.redirect', $this->here);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `$this->referer()`.

**login function**

```
function login()
{
   if ($this->Auth->user())
   {
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
        exit();
   }
}
```